# Not able to update foreign key value using GORM with Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, go-gorm

There are multiple teams and every team has multiple players (one-to-many).
One player can belong to only a single unique team (one-to-one)

I am using the below two gorm models:

```
// Team has many Players, TeamID is the foreign key
type Team struct {
    ID            uint      `gorm:"primarykey"`
    Name          string    
    Players       []Player
}

type Player struct {
    ID          uint      `gorm:"primarykey"`
    FirstName   string
    LastName    string    
    TeamID      uint      
}
```

```
For "players" table:
Foreign-key constraints:
    "fk_teams_players" FOREIGN KEY (team_id) REFERENCES teams(id)
```

When I am trying to update a player's team_id (which exists in "teams" table), GORM is not doing so in the database while it is able to update any other column value.

```
// Returns player by id from db
var player models.Player = GetPlayerByID(playerID)
player.TeamID = newTeamID
player.FirstName = "Robin"
db.Save(&player)
```

The above statement updates the `FirstName` but the `TeamID` remains unchanged.

I am manually able to update the `TeamID` value in the database using SQL query but not able to do so using GORM.

I have tried two other ways to update but both have the same behaviour as above.

```
db.Exec("UPDATE players SET team_id=? , first_name=? WHERE id = ?",newTeamID, "Robin", player.ID)

db.Model(&player).Updates(model.Player{TeamID: newTeamID, FirstName: "Robin"})
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I am missing here?

Comment: Have you tried constraints as ``gorm:"constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL; foreignkey:UserID; association_foreignkey:TeamID"`` . Please check careful spellings in string.

Comment: Some times it happens due to `OnUpdate:CASCADE`